# Start and stop solr server from scala program

Tags: scala, solr, embedded-jetty, scalatest

Solr comes with packaged jetty jar start.jar in example folder . For my scalatest automation I need to control solr start and stop from my scalatest module . How can I do that ? Please guide and suggest.

Comment: As I am not familiar with Scala, I could only offer a Java sample. Would that help you?

Comment: sure i can correlate and work my way out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have [written a JUnit rule](https://github.com/chriseverty/solrsample/blob/master/src/main/java/de/cheffe/solrsample/rule/JettySolrServerResource.java) is intended for integration tests. This rule starts and stops the Jetty server that is wrapped by Solr on behalf of the class `JettySolrRunner`.

The relevant part to start Solr with the embedded Jetty is

```java
File solrXml = new File("/solr/home/solr.xml");
File solrHomeDir = solrXml.getParentFile();

int port = 8080;
String context = "/solr";
// use org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.JettySolrRunner
JettySolrRunner jettySolr 
  = new JettySolrRunner(solrHomeDir.getAbsolutePath(), context, port);

boolean waitUntilTheSolrWebAppHasStarted = true;
jettySolr.start(waitUntilTheSolrWebAppHasStarted);
```

Stopping that server is rather straight forward

```java
jettySolr.stop();
```